# freeswitch plugins for check status of freeswitch for nagios monitoring system

Tags: plugins, centos, freeswitch

I want check free switch plug-in to check free switch status OK or critical for cent OS 
Nagios monitoring system
please any one have idea or plug-in please give me.....

Answer (score 0):

You want this: https://github.com/kjhosein/nagios-freeswitch-plugin

Some other introductory info from the author is here: https://serverfault.com/a/545586/151583